# Google chart line, combine multiple tooltips into one

Tags: google-visualization

Can someone explain me how to combine multiple tooltips into one, similar to what Google is doing in Google Search Console. I did not found any example in https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart achieving this result (check below image):

[Google Search Console Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AvHB.png)

I guess Google is using the Google Chart libraries.

Additionally, you can see in the example above, the vertical line when you hover over a specific date. How that is done as well?

Comment: try setting this chart option --> `aggregationTarget: 'category'`

Comment: it does not work, but i found out that what i was looking for is: focusTarget: 'category'

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to add the following parameter in the options:

**focusTarget: 'category'**

> 'category' - Focus on a grouping of all data points along the major axis. Correlates to a row in the data table.

More info can be found in Google page: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart